# iterate through a list of widgets based on a list of objects in a formula

Tags: flutter, list, loops, dart, widget

I am trying to display a certain series of widgets based on objects contained in a formula. Here is how I am assigning the widgets to a variable based on their type.

```
      var l = TankFormulaLength(length: tankSpec.tankSpecs.imperialLength);
      var w = TankFormulaWidth(width: tankSpec.tankSpecs.imperialWidth);
      var h = TankFormulaHeight(height: tankSpec.tankSpecs.imperialHeight);
      var d = TankFormulaDiameter(diameter: tankSpec.tankSpecs.imperialDiameter);

      List<Widget> tankMeasurements = [l, w, h, d];
```

Here is where these are being used.

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
     ...tankFormula(tankMeasurements,
        tankSpec.tankSpecs.formula),
    ],
),
```

The formula is pulled from an api call that happens based on a tank specification and is delivered as show below..currently I am printing it to the console so I can see what formula each tank spec is using.[image]

in my tankFormula function, I want to take the specific formula and use it to iterate through my list of widgets and only return the ones specific to the formula. Currently I am able to make all of them show up, because they are not being filtered.

```
List<Widget> tankFormula(formulaComponents, formula) {
  List<Widget> calculatedFormula = [];

  print(formula);
  return formulaComponents;
}
```

I am unsure how to get the end result I am looking for. As shown in the screenshot below, I only needs the fields from the formula, 'Length' and 'Diameter', to show up as those are the only ones used in this particular formula for this specific tank specification. In other instances, it could be some of the additional fields i.e. 'Width or 'Height'. Again, based on the formula returned from the API. The additional fields 'Product', 'Tank Capacity', and 'Sensor Offset', will always be displayed.

[image]

I am aware that calculatedFormula is not being used. I created this variable to hold the returned List of Widgets that will be displayed on the screen. I am stuck and unsure how to move forward. Thank you sincerely for your help in advance!

Comment: What data type is `formula` ? Is it a list of Strings ?

Comment: And if it is a list of Strings.  Do you mean that if you only receive a "w" in the formula, then you only want to present the widget called `TankFormulaWidth`?

Comment: @RobertSandberg Yes, formula is returned from the API as a list of strings. And yes, your second question is correct. If I return a W, I want it to display the widget TankFormulaWidth. The formula wont ever be just one of those elements though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this problem. Because I was receiving a specific value from the api for each portion of the formula I needed to make sure I was passing that down to my custom widget through the function I had created and then checking to see which variables the formula contains.

```
    List<Widget> tankFormula(l, w, h, d, formula) {
      List<Widget> calculatedFormula = [];
        if (formula.contains('l')) {
          calculatedFormula.add(TankFormulaLength(length: l));
        }
        if (formula.contains('w')) {
          calculatedFormula.add(TankFormulaWidth(width: w));
        }
        if (formula.contains('h')) {
          calculatedFormula.add(TankFormulaHeight(height: h));
        }
        if (formula.contains('d')) {
          calculatedFormula.add(TankFormulaDiameter(diameter: d));
        }

        print(formula);
        return calculatedFormula;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this perhaps what you're looking for?

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        if (list.contains('l')) TankFormulaLength(),
        if (list.contains('h')) TankFormulaHeight(),
        if (list.contains('w')) TankFormulaWidth(),
        if (list.contains('d')) TankFormulaDiameter(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

This assumes that `list` is your array of strings, which can look like:

```
  var list = ['l', 'h', 'w', 'd'];
```

Comment: I would have to iterate through formula and add the separate strings to list and then check list.contains.  SO this could potentially work. It's a bit different than how I was going about it, but that doesn't mean it couldn't work.

Comment: @Mackina I am not sure what you mean with iterate through formula? Isn't formula one list that at most contains 4 elements?

Comment: I meant iterate through the list based on the formula. I apologize for that mistype.

Comment: You dont need to iterate through it, or at least I don't see why you would.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by "void void" is perfectly legit. If you want, for some reason, to iterate over the list, then this is a separate approach.

```
return Column(
        children: list.map<Widget>((e) {
          switch(e) {
            case 'l': return TankFormulaLength(...);
            case 'h': return TankFormulaHeight(...);
            case 'w': return TankFormulaWidth(...);
            case 'd': return TankFormulaDiameter(...);
          }
          return const SizedBox.shrink();
        ).toList(),
      );
```

Comment: However in my original question, I stated that the formula will never consist of one element. It will always be multiples. Height x Length, Length x Diameter, etc. I need the code to be able to accept whatever formula is given by the API and use that as the parameter in which to display the specific fields. This solution seems to only show one of the parameters being chosen.

Comment: This answer doesn't only handle one parameter. Try it before neglecting it if you are unsure about what the code does :)